# jquery .text() doesn't work online but do work on local server

Tags: jquery, html

I dynamically generate this dropdownlist with php, i get the values with jquery and .text() them in another id
My code:

```
 <td><select name="maat[<?php echo $key?>]" id="mate<?php echo $key?>">
    <?php if ($prod->type==='overige') {?>
            <option value="5xl">5xl</option>
            <option value="4xl">4xl</option>
             <option value="3xl">3xl</option>
             <option value="2xl">2xl</option>
             <option value="xl">xl</option>
             <option value="l">l</option>
             <option value="m" selected="selected">m</option>
              <option value="s">s</option>
              <option value="xs">xs</option>
             <option value="2xs">2xs</option>
             <option value="3xs">3xs</option>
             <option value="4xs">4xs</option>
             <option value="5xs">5xs</option>
             <?php } else {?>
           <option value="30-33">38-40</option>
           <option value="34-35">41-43</option>
         <option value="39-42" selected="selected">44-46</option>
            <option value="43-45">47-49</option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select></td>

 <td ><input type="number" min="0" name="aantal[<?php echo $key?>]" id="aantal<?php echo $key?>" placeholder="0" class="inputQuant text-center" ></td>

<td class=" text-center celll" id="prijsMaat<?php echo $key?>"><?php echo $prod->price ?></td>
```

my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#controle2").click(function () {

            $("#aantal<?php echo $key?>").each(function (index) {
                console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
                let a = $(this).val();
                console.log(a);
                let  num3 =<?php echo $prod->price ?>;
                console.log(a*num3);
                $("#aantalOverige<?php echo $key?>").text(a);
                $("#totaaloverige<?php echo $key?>").text(a*num3);
            });


            $("#mate<?php echo $key?>").each(function () {
                let b = $(this).val();
                console.log(b);
                $("#waardeOverige<?php echo $key?>").text(b);
                console.log($("#waardeOverige<?php echo $key?>"));
            });
        });
    });
    //
</script>
```

On my live server i can see the results from myconsole log but the .text() not
[printscreen of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7oGh.png)

Comment: If this is a jQuery problem, remove the PHP tag and include the rendered HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: Start by looking at the rendered HTML and see if the expected values are being injected from the PHP

Comment: miken32 done,  @Patrick q check my printscreen of the html output, my console logs from       "a,a*num3,b"      are correct